# NuGet selecting wrong DLL (32-bits vs 64-bits)

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

I am using a .net NuGet which contains a DLL compiled to native code. That native DLL comes in two versions, a 32-bits build and a 64-bits build.

The nuget uses a ".targets" file in its "build" folder to determine which DLL to copy. The targets file looks something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!-- Ensure that for Framework projects the correct DLL is copied to the build directory -->
  
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' OR '$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU' ">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\win-x64\native\FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' ">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\win-x86\native\FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

However, even though I am using a 64-bits computer and using a 64-bits build target, it's always the 32-bits version that ends up in the "Bin" folder of my builds.

Does anyone know how this process works, and what determines which platform NuGet will decide to target? How do I make the nuget-restore-and-build process select the 64-bits DLL? (the build is performed using either Visual Studio or msbuild)

Answer (score 0):

The targets file that you posted does not match the targets file of the latest version (4.2.4) of the [FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise/4.2.4) NuGet package, where `AnyCPU` matches the `x86` platform instead of the `x64` platform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!-- Ensure that for Framework projects the correct DLL is copied to the build directory -->
  
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\win-x64\native\FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' OR '$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU' ">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\win-x86\native\FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>FiftyOne.DeviceDetection.Hash.Engine.OnPremise.Native.dll</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

So in order to have the correct native dll to end up in your output directory, you should either add `<Platform>x64</Platform>` in your csproj file or build your project by specifying the `Platform` property like this:

```
dotnet build /p:Platform=x64 MyApp.csproj
```

Comment: The modified file was an attempt on my part to fix the issue, I also tried with the original unmodified file to no avail.

Unfortunately, passing Platform=x64 does not seem to help either